# What is the meaning of Lisa's words?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

**[SOURCE](https://www.moviedialogs.com/movies/a-single-man)**

Lisa & her male friend Michael are discussing her
meeting with young man.

> Lisa: The other day at the car wash a young man looked me up and down
>   and asked me if I was a natural blond.
>
> Michael: What did you say?
>
> Lisa: I looked him straight in the eye and I said: "**Well, let's say if
>   I stood on my head, I'd be a natural brunette with lovely breath.**"
>
> Michael: You didn't.(*with laughs*)
>
> Lisa: I did.(*with laughs*)

What is the meaning of Lisa's words in this context?

I used **Strong** format on the words which i didn't understand.

Comment: She means that if she were to stand on her head, the hair on her body that is _not_ died blonde would be where her head usually is relative to the person she is addressing. Depending upon her self-confidence, the reference to lovely breath is either ironic or proud.

Comment: This is more about reading comprehension rather than learning English. Could you add which words or phrases are causing difficulty? As I read it, "looked me up and down" and "if I stood on my head" are the key points. Beyond that you have to use your imagination, though "natural brunette" can refer to hair that would not normally be colored.

Comment: @user3169 I agree that the question is marginal for ELL. but it's the OP's first question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think you mean "*dyed* blond" ...

Comment: @Robusto Yep, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Culturally, what you need to understand is most people who *dye* the hair on their head, will not dye their *pubic hair* and so the color of their *pubic hair* would be indicative of their *natural hair colour*.

Lisa is saying that she is a *natural brunette*, and that she dyes the hair on her head *blonde*.

Comment: Hello peter, I didn't understand why you mentioned **pubic hair** in answer? you can see her words she never mentioned **pubic hair** in her statement.

Comment: It's very indirect, but I agree that is the implication that's meant.  This sort of indirect reference is common in jokes, especially dirty ones.

Comment: what is you are referring here by using the word **that** in this sentence: "she **that** dyes the hair on her head blonde".

Comment: @user57099 The words spoken by the character in the film are not the actress's words. They are written in a screenplay by a screenwriter, and the references are often subtle, ribald, humorous, etc.. The objective is to entertain the audience. Films in English are not intended as English grammar lessons. In your native language, are there any jokes?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god guys, it's a joke about how her natural hair color is brown so if she stood in her head her pubic hair would be exposed and brown and her breath is a representation for the smell of her vagina that would also be exposed if she stood on her head, it's a very dirty joke but is not complicated in context sheesh

Comment: This answer does provide new information, complementing the existing, accepted answer, in explaining the "stand on her head" part which was overlooked in the other answer. But I would recommend changing the format and wording so that your answer reads more formal and serious.